# Don't understand why meteorjs publish does not update

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to understand meteorjs publish and subscribe.  I wrote a dynamic publish function:

```
Meteor.publish("customers",function(f) {
  var re=null;
  if ('undefined' !== typeof f) {
    re = new RegExp("^"+f,"i");
  }
  return customers2.find({$and: [{shipto: {$ne:""}}, {shipto: {$regex: re}}]},{sort: {shipto:1}});
});
```

That gets all the customer that start with a certain letter.

Then I subscribe at startup:

```
Meteor.subscribe("customers","");
```

Shows all customers.  Now I have a input box on my customers page that points to this event function:

```
function filterCustomers(e,t) {
  var f = $(e.target).val();
  Meteor.subscribe("customers",f);
}
```

The new subscription does not seem to update the customer list at all.

Then I tried at startup

```
Meteor.subscribe("customers",Session.get("customer_filter"));
```

and this in the filter function:

```
function filterCustomers(e,t) {
  var f = $(e.target).val();
  Session.set('customer_filter',f);
}
```

But updating a session variable does not update the publish.

I've put the subscribe in an Deps.autorun but that didn't help.

I'm trying to avoid sending my entire customer database down the wire.  Why is the subcribe never updating?  What do you have to do to do that?  What don't I understand about publish and subscribe?

---

Following the suggestion below, extracted out a simple app:

```
Customers = new Meteor.Collection("customers");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Session.setDefault("customer_filter","");

Deps.autorun(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe('customers',Session.get('customer_filter'));
});

Template.customers.events({
  'click .dof' :function(e,t) {
    Session.set("customer_filter", $(e.target).attr("find"));
  }
});

Template.customers.customers = function() {
  return Customers.find();
}

Template.customers.currentFilter = function() {
  return " | "+Session.get("customer_filter");
};

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
// Publish complete set of lists to all clients.
  Meteor.publish('customers', function (filter) {
    var re=null;
    if (filter) {
      re = new RegExp("^"+filter,"i");
     }
     return Customers.find({$and:[{shipto: {$ne:""}},{shipto: {$regex: re}}]},{sort:{shipto:1}});
  });

}
```

And the template

```
<body>
  {{> customers}}
</body>

<template name="customers">
  <h2>Customer List {{currentFilter}}
  <div id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" class="search-query span6" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
</h2>
<button find="" class="dof">ALL</button>
<button find="f" class="dof">F</button>
<button find="g" class="dof">G</button>
<button find="h" class="dof">H</button>
<button find="i" class="dof">I</button>
<button find="j" class="dof">J</button>

<table class="table table-striped" border=1>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Ship To</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Attn</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each customers}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{shipto}}</td>
        <td>{{address}}, {{city}}, {{state}} {{zip}}</td>
        <td>{{attn}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

Very weird behavior.  The buttons do not update the data.  If I change a little code, the server refreshes and I sometimes get one update.  Then more button clicks but no UI changes.  Tried adding Deps.refresh in the click handler but no luck.

Looks like only modifying the server code really forces a refresh...  Maybe a UI issue and not a data issue?  PS How can I see the data in the browser

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to subscribe is:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('customers', Session.get('customer_filter'));
});
```

If you've tried this and it didn't work, the error is somewhere else.

---

In order for reactivity to work, you need two things: autorun context and reactive data source.

Autorun context is a function that watches on one or several dependencies and rerun whenever one of them changes. In this case, it's provided by `Deps.autorun` function.

Reactive data source is an object capable of notifying context that it has changed its value. In the above case, it's the Session variable.

You cannot have reactivity with only one of these factors, to make a function rerun itself automatically you need to provide both.

Comment: It also works just by constructing the publish with observe or observeChanges.  No need for Deps autorun.

Comment: Where is the deps.autorun placed?  In the Meteor.startup or just anywhere in the client code, or in the filterCustomers function.  PS so far, it's not working...

Comment: It should be either directly in the client code, or in `Meteor.startup()`. You can embed it in a function if you want, but then it`smyour responsibility to invoke that function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the mailing list:

Avital Oliver  Jul 27 10:04AM -0700

Try {shipto: re} rather than {shipto : {$regex: re}}. (I think it's a bug
that we found at devshop two days ago)

The first answer certainly is the right way to do a subscribe.  However, it was still broken.  This fixes the last part.

Posting to help other poor souls...